# Does MATLAB allow a uicontrol button to be placed within a cell in a uitable?

Tags: matlab, button, matlab-uitable

I want to place a uicontrol button in each row of a uitable. Does MATLAB have the native functionality for this, or do I need to use Java/HTML?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible using standard MATLAB. You can use the `CellSelectionCallback` and `CellEditCallback` of the `uitable` together with the `MouseClickedCallback` of the corresponding `uitablepeer` to provide a button-like functionality for standard table cells. See [this thread](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/270514) for more infor on the `MouseClickedCallback`.

An easier way is probably to use Java tables right from the beginning if your setup allows it.