# Button in Matlab GUI Table Cell

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

Is there a way to **add a button in table cell** in Matlab GUI so that each button can perform action depending on which row its in?

[Sample of What I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4slQr.png)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11263140/4806927) might be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without resorting to using java controls (something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14225-java-based-data-table) could get you going); however, you could setup a `CellSelectionCallback` on the `uitable` and determine what to execute based on the row.

```
function callback(eventData)
    if eventData.Indices(2) == 3
        fprintf('Clicked Row %d\n', eventData.Indices(1))
    end
end

fig = figure()

data = {'a', '1', 'Click Me';
        'b', '2', 'Click Me'};

u = uitable(fig, 'data', data, 'CellSelectionCallback', @(s,e)callback(e));
```

If you really want button-like styling you could exploit the ability to put HTML within your cells.

```
data = {'a', '1', '<html><input type="submit" value="Click Me"/></html>';
        'b', '2', '<html><input type="submit" value="Click Me"/></html>'};
```

Comment: Nice workaround with the `html` tags. It doesn't resize beautifully but it does the trick ... and doesn't need any java hack.